# can we automatically wait the required time for smartmontools/smartctl?

Tags: smartctl, smartmontools

```
Can we do something like this in a script (preferably zsh):

smartctl -t long /dev/sda
smartctl -t long /dev/sdb
smartctl -t long /dev/sdc

[Wait however long smartctl needs]

smartctl -H /dev/sda
smartctl -H /dev/sdb
smartctl -H /dev/sdc
```

As is obvious I'm just trying to automate this.

Comment: The problem is that you don't know how long `smartctl` takes, do you? This is not a shell problem. You can wait a reasonable time (in a loop, for each device) and check whether the test has finished.

Comment: That's exactly the question.  Does smartctl make some mechanism available by which the shell can determine that it's finished it's tests.  When the tests start, there is an expected finish time, I suppose that string might be grabbed and go from there, but I'm asking if there's a more direct method.

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 possibilities. `smartctl -c` will list the capabilities of the device, which includes lines like

```
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:      (   1) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:      (  48) minutes.
```

So you can simply read these and do a sleep for the required short or long time.

Secondly, whilst a test is in progress the same `-c` option will list the current status of any test, eg:

```
Offline data collection status:  (0x03) Offline data collection activity
  is in progress.
Self-test execution status:      ( 247) Self-test routine in progress...
  70% of test remaining.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:    (   44) seconds.
```

So you can poll every few minutes and wait for the time left to return to 0 and the other fields have their final values:

```
Offline data collection status:  (0x02) Offline data collection activity
  was completed without error.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
  without error or no self-test has ever 
  been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:    (    0) seconds.
```

Answer (score 2):

It ain't pretty but this seems to work.  Could easily be modified to handle an arbitrary number of disks.  Mods welcome.

```
#!/usr/bin/zsh
#set -x

outputmsg () { echo -e "\e[35;1m$@\e[0m"; }
infomsg ()   { echo -e "\e[36;1m$@\e[0m"; }

smartctl -X /dev/sda &> /dev/null
wait_time_greatest=$( smartctl -t short /dev/sda | grep 'Please wait' | sed 's,^\(Please wait \)\([[:digit:]]*\)\(.*\),\2,' )

smartctl -X /dev/sdb &> /dev/null
wait_time_new=$( smartctl -t short /dev/sdb | grep 'Please wait' | sed 's,^\(Please wait \)\([[:digit:]]*\)\(.*\),\2,' )

[ "$wait_time_new" -gt "$wait_time_greatest" ] && wait_time_greatest="$wait_time_new"

wait_time_greatest=$((wait_time_greatest + 1)) #To be safe?

infomsg "\nWe'll be done in $wait_time_greatest minutes ...\n"
sleep "$[wait_time_greatest]m"

outputmsg "Disk sda:"   # Strange that the report doesn't contain the disk ID.
echo -e \e[0m       # Must reset the color!
smartctl -H /dev/sda

outputmsg "Disk sdb:"
echo -e \e[0m       # Must reset the color!
smartctl -H /dev/sdb

# Because smartctl seems to screw this up and it needs to be redone:
hdparm -S60y /dev/sda
hdparm -S60y /dev/sdb
```